# Does throw() (i.e. __declspec(nothrow)) give real benefits in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception

Focusing on Visual C++, have you ever experienced significant performance gains in C++ code using `throw()` (i.e. `__declspec(nothrow)`) non-throwing specification?
Does it really help the optimizer?
Are there any benchmarks showing performance gains?

I found different (opposite) advice on the Internet:

[Boost exception-specification rationale](http://www.boost.org/development/requirements.html#Exception-specification) is *against* `throw()`, instead Larry Osterman seems to be *in favor* of it in his blog post: [Why add a throw() to your methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/03/22/558390.aspx)

(I'd like to clarify that **I'm interested in VC++ specific code**; I know that in GCC the `throw()` specification can actually be a "pessimization" due to run-time checks.)

**P.S.** Reading ATL headers, I found that `throw()` is used pervasively; moreover, I found a convenient C++ RAII `unique_handle` class in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288076.aspx) that uses `throw()` specification as well.

Comment: This really has to do with your own design, if your function has a reason to trow something, then do so, just remember exceptions are for exceptional circumstances, not errors. And as far as the run time hit on using exceptions, most of the argument is about the time it takes for the exception to propagate to a handler, coupled with the extra run time checks done with exceptions. Alas, if your writing something highly performance critical, you may consider not using exceptions at all. But for most non critical code, exception use is fine. That's just my two cents on it.

Comment: This is pretty subjective.  But the examples you give are opposites, Boost is fretting about exception specifications just not working well.  The C++11 committee agreed and deprecated them.  Larry is talking about ways that the compiler *could* take advantage of them to generate more optimal code, an entirely different angle.  Could work but I got fed up with the optimizer outsmarting me to provide an example.  The optimization is awfully slight anyway and getting pretty irrelevant because 64-bit code uses function tables.

Comment: Think not about micro-performance, think about clarity.

Comment: His question was specifically about performance, not what is good design. I'm curious to hear answers on this as well!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: If you write a component that is used lots of time in an app, maybe small optimizations can add up to something significant. I find `throw()` used pervasively in ATL headers, and it is used in this `unique_handle` class [in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288076.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSVC compiler treats it as an optimization hint, yes.

Boost has to be cross-platform, they have to go for something that's safe and efficient on a variety of compilers. And as the boost docs say, *some* compilers might generate slower code when `throw()` is specified, and in many cases, compilers can deduce that no exception is thrown *regardless* of whether there is a `throw()` specification, so for Boost, the safest approach is to just never use throw-specifications.

But if you're targeting MSVC specifically, then `throw()` effectively tells the compiler not to generate exception-handling code for the function, which may give a speedup in cases where the function was too complex for the compiler to determine that no exception could be thrown.

Comment: So, for a simple non-throwing getter, adding throw() would be useless?

Comment: Very likely. Of course, to be certain, you'd have to test it. And it might depend on a few other factors. If the getter is defined in a different compilation unit, the compiler won't know what it does, or whether or not it might throw, when calling it. So there, `throw()` might still make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I add it, but its not to help the optimizer its to help me write more correct code.

```
class X
{
    public:
        void swap(X& rhs) throw(); // Swap better not ever throw
                                    // If it does there is something else
                                    // much more seriously wrong
};
```

Comment: I think you have a typo: _throws()_ should be `throw()`.

Comment: oops. That what happens when you r write without compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Main problem with `throw()` is that code inside function marked as `throw()` *can* throw.
For example, this will work perfectly:

```
void foo() throw()
{
    throw "haha\n";
}

int main()
{
    try {
        foo();
    }
    catch(const char* s) {
        std::cout << s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that foo would not `throw` to `main`, of cause. And you will not catch the exception (as if you comment `throw()` specifier). Instead, compiler will wrap code function with `try{}catch()` block. When exception is generated it will be handled by global handler (that will mean your program crash by default).

Note, that compiler *have to* wrap function code with `try{}cath()` block, unless compiler is sure, that inner code has no possibility to generate exception.

As a result, some optimization with the *caller* of `foo` can be done, but things get more complex *inside* `foo`.

**EDIT:**

Things with `__declspec(nothrow)` is different: As [Microsft tells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49147z04%28v=vs.71%29.aspx),

> This attribute tells the compiler that the declared function **and the
>   functions it calls** never throw an exception.

It means, that compiler can omit `try{}catch()` wrapper code.

**EDIT2**
Actually, Microsoft violates standard behavior and does not generate warpper for `throw()`. Well, then you can use `throw()` to improve performance.

Comment: In MSVC, throw() is semantically equivalent to __declspec(nothrow).